# for loop: get the title of the first element of an entries field

Tags: templating, forloop, entries-field

I want to get the title of the first element from a entries field in a for loop. I think its easier to understand with a code example:

```
{% set programs = craft.entries.section('program_point').block.first().title('first-block') %}
{% for program in programs %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

`block` is an entries field. And the loop should only consider entries where the title of the first element in `block`is *first-block*.

When I tried this, I always got an error:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("title") on a null variable

But when I did this:

```
{% set programs = craft.entries.section('program_point') %}
{% for program in programs %}
        {% if program.block.first().title == 'first-block' %}
             ...
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

all worked fine. 
So how can I check the title of the first element in the for loop?

Comment: Have you tried to put `.first()` before `.block` ? I think it has something to do with the order of this line.

Comment: I think this returns the first entry of the section *program_point*. But I need the first element of `block`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. What about adding `.find()` at the end?

Comment: Sadly the same result

Answer (score 1):

I could be not following correctly, so I apologize if I'm way off here.

If you want to grab *all* entries that are selected in your `block` field, but only want to single out the first one, you could do something like this:

```
<h2>Program Points</h2>
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('program_point') %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
    {% else %}
        <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The [twig for loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) has some pretty cool stuff built in that you could leverage to check for the first entry.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But I think this is not what I'm searching for. I only want the entries where the first element in `block` has the title 'first-block'. Maybe now you understand what I mean?

Comment: Will you be having more than one entry with a title of `first-block`?

Comment: yes i will have